# Prove the fractional field $Q(\mathbb{Z})$ of the integral domain $\Bbb Z$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

prove $Q(\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Q}$

I have already proven that for some integral domain R, if we take $R \times R \backslash \{0\}$ it is a field under the operations. $(a,b)+(c,d) = (ad+bc, bd)$ and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac,bd)$

I know $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and $Q(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$ is a field under the operations.

Can I perform the subfield test on $Q(\mathbb{Z})$ to show it is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ then perform the subfield test on $\mathbb{Q}$ and show it is a subfield of $Q(\mathbb{Z})$ thus they are equal

Comment: You should try to find an isomorphism between $Q(\Bbb Z)$ and $\Bbb Q$.  Can you think of a way to map elements of one to the other that satisfies field isomorphism axioms (i.e., the additive and multiplicative identities should be preserved, and addition and multiplication shoul dbe preserved)?

Comment: Well... how do you define $\Bbb Q$ if not by $Q(\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Q$?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbf Q$?

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Same reaction at the same time :o)

Comment: @Bernard Here's a cookie: o  (lol)

Comment: @user46944 $\phi(n) = [(n,1)]$ it would perserve the additive and multiplicative identity and so would multiplication and addition.

Comment: @oliverjones It looks like you are defining your map to go from $\Bbb Q$ to $Q(\Bbb Z)$, which is fine.  But you only defined where integers go.  Where does $\frac{a}{b}$ go?

Comment: well that would go from Z to Q(Z). then from Q(Z) to Q would be. for (a,b) in Q(Z). let $\psi : Q(Z) \to Q$ be defined as $\psi(a,b)= \frac{a}{b}$

Comment: @oliverjones Yeah, I agree with your map.  I know you were thinking of $\Bbb Q$ as an entity that already exists, and $Q(\Bbb Z)$ as a field we construct from $\Bbb Z$, and you wanted to show they are the same field.  If you look up how to rigorously define $\Bbb Q$ from $\Bbb Z$, you'll see that it's actually exactly the same way as we define $Q(\Bbb Z)$.  (That's what the other comments were getting at.)  But I suggested you come up with a map because I knew you were thinking about the rationals as the field you are familiar with, and not really thinking about its construction.

Comment: @user46944 what about the issue with equivalence classes. Like $\phi(a,b) = \phi(c,d) \implies a/b=c/d$ which of course is true but  its possible that $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$ like 1/2=100/200

Comment: @oliverjones That's why you should look at a rigorous construction of $\Bbb Q$.  Both $\Bbb Q$ and $Q(\Bbb Z)$ are sets of equivalence classes, and actually with the same equivalence relation.  Why do we say $\frac{1}{2}$ is equivalent to $\frac{100}{200}$ in $\Bbb Q$?  Because $1(200) = 2(100)$.  We say $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are equivalent in $\Bbb Q$ if $ad = bc$.  That's exactly the same equivalence relation for $Q(\Bbb Z)$, except instead of denoting our elements $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, we denote them $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Comment: So, your map $\phi$ is sending the *equivalence class* of $\frac{a}{b}$, i.e., the set of $\frac{c}{d}$ such that $ad = bc$, to the equivalence class $(a,b)$, i.e., the set of $(c,d)$ such that $ad = bc$.  Is it starting to become clear that $Q(\Bbb Z)$ is really $\Bbb Q$?  It's just easier on our eyes to write $\frac{a}{b}$ instead of $(a,b)$, but that's just notation.  Underneath the notation, these fields are exactly the same because they are defined in the same way.